# Active admin redirects loop after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, activeadmin

My Rails system was working fine and I was able to access the admin panel without any problems.

But since a couple of days after signup it goes in to the redirect loop, I'm not sure why is this happening. My routes.rb and application_controller.rb are the following.

**routes.rb**

```
root :to => 'home#index'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  match 'ADMIN' => 'admin/admin_users#index'

  match 'admin/wallet_withdraws/confirm' => 'admin/wallet_withdraws#confirm'
```

And **application_controller.rb** has following code in it.

```
def authenticate_active_admin_user!
    render :text => "Tets" and return
        authenticate_admin_user!
        unless current_admin_user.role?(:superadmin)
            flash[:alert] = "You are not authorized to access this resource!"
            redirect_to root_path
        end
  end
```

I'm not able to access any link, not just root of admin which is `admin/admin_users#index`

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you by chance using Devise as well? If so, ensure your Devise routes precede your ActiveAdmin routes.